# Is The Amazing Spider-Man part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

Spider-Man is a Marvel franchise, just like Avengers and X-Men.  When they rebooted the Hulk in 2008 it was to incorporate the character into the Marvel Cinematic Universe.
The Amazing Spider-Man opens on July 3, 2012 in the USA and is a reboot of the character. Spider-Man 3 was released in 2007. It's only been five years since the last movie for this character!

Based on what they did with the Hulk, it seems likely that they're rebooting the series so that they can include the character in the next Avengers movie.  Spider-Man is even a member of the New Avengers in print.

Has anyone confirmed whether or not the new Amazing Spider-Man movie is part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Comment: [List of films based on Marvel Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_Marvel_Comics)

Comment: @sunpech Kalamane's asking about the [Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) not Marvel comics turned into movies in general.

Comment: @Keen The list shows the production studios that made each of the films. That's how it's relevant.

Comment: @sunpech That detail does help explain the link.

Comment: [HE IS NOOOOOOOWWWW](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/feb/10/spider-man-to-join-marvel-superheroes-in-shared-movie-universe)

Comment: (“it seems likely that they're rebooting the series so that they can include the character in the next Avengers movie” — ironically, they were kinda rebooting the series to *prevent* Spider-Man’s rights from reverting to the company that could put him into the MCU.)

Comment: @Kalamane - Given that a bounty has been posted to draw attention for updated, more accurate answers, you might want to consider changing the accepted answer for the benefit of  viewers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes*

**The Amazing Spider-Man*'s Andrew Garfield

> starred as one of *three* Spider-Men in the newly released *Spider-Man: No Way Home*. The other two were portrayed by Tom Holland and Tobey Maguire.

***Spider-Man: No Way Home* is MCU canon**. Therefore, Andrew Garfield's "Amazing Spider-Man" is part of the MCU, and the film *The Amazing Spider-Man* is MCU canon, just **not on the same timeline/universe as the rest of the MCU**. There are a lot of differences between the MCU's world and *The Amazing Spider-Man*'s, however, **it is present as an alternate timeline in the MCU.**

In addition, the 2021 series *Loki* introduced us to the idea of **infinite variants of various people, including Loki, Mobius, Renslayer, Kang, and so on, due to infinite timelines.** This means that Garfield's Peter Parker and Maguire's Peter Parker **are both passable as just variants** for retcon purposes, but their stories are therefore MCU canon.

**Both Garfield's Spider-Man *and* Maguire's Spider-Man retain memories of the events as their times as Spider-man, and it matches up with the events of the movies:**

> PARKER (GARFIELD): You know, Max was the sweetest guy... until he fell into a vat of electric eels.
> PARKER (MAGUIRE): That'll do it.
> <sup>*Spider-Man: No Way Home*</sup>
> **Garfield's Parker remembers what happened to Max Dillon (Electro).**

Another example:

> PARKER (MAGUIRE): I've made a serum for Dr. Osborn before.
> <sup>*Spider-Man: No Way Home*</sup>
> This references the events of the first Sam Raimi trilogy Spider-Man movie (*Spider-Man*, 2002).

Furthermore,

> both new Spider-Men remember about their villains and what happened to them. It's even reasonable to assume that each had killed their respective villains, due to Maguire's Spider-Man looking much older and Garfield's Spider-Man remembering Gwen Stacy's loss, which came *after* he had killed both Connors and Electro.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage your guess is correct and the other answers are invalidated. Here's an up-to-date one.

Comment: Although the “U” in MCU does stand for “universe” (and the “M” doesn’t stand for “multiverse”. It’s definitely in the Prism of Endless Possibility™©

Comment: Except that the events of the two non-canon spider-man films don't appear to have played out the same way. For example, Electro looks entirely different and Doc Oc is nearly 20 years older

Comment: The Electro argument could be made that it was caused by Holland's Parker's universe's "different energy"

Comment: Oops, I started another bounty to make up for this one

Answer (score 24):

The new *Amazing Spider-man* film is not part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.  It's Sony's newest Spider-man film.  They're required to keep making them or the rights will revert to Marvel, which would then allow Marvel to make their own Spider-man films in addition to including Spidey in the Marvel Cinematic Universe films.  For more information, [see my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16068/1027) to a related question.

Comment: *They're required to keep making them or the rights will revert*....  Is that why they keep making Transformers movies too?

Comment: @CamelBlues Honestly, I'd have to research that.  But I figure the ridiculous amount of money they keep making is why they keep making Transformers films.

Answer (score 11):

### No, it is still not part of the MCU

According to [this article](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-Spider-Man-Fit-MCU-According-Marvel-President-72275.html) and Wikipedia, Tom Holland will be playing Spider-Man in the new movies, whereas Andrew Garfield played him in *The Amazing Spider-Man*.

Kevin Feige, president of Marvel Studios, has also made it very clear that this is a [new version of Peter Parker:](https://sciencefiction.com/2015/04/13/kevin-feige-reveals-mcu-spider-man-details/)

> In terms of the age of what we believe Peter Parker is, I’d say 15-16 is right…We want to play with Spider-Man in the high school years because
> frankly there’ve been five Spider-Man films and the amazing thing
> about it is, even though there’ve been five Spider-Man films, there
> are so many things from the comics that haven’t been done yet.

Note that this contradicts *The Amazing Spider-Man*.
According to [Feige](https://collider.com/spider-man-kevin-feige-confirms-peter-parker-in-high-school/):

> I think it was midway through the first film that he graduated high
> school. At the beginning of the second Marc Webb film, he graduated
> high school. And some of my favorite Spider-Man arcs and Spider-Man
> stories, he’s in high school for a lot of it.

The Marc Webb films are *The Amazing Spider-Man* and *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*.
Since Spider-Man will be in high school for *Captain America: Civil War*, it is clear that Feige is going for a very different story for Peter than happened in *The Amazing Spider-Man*.

[Similarly, from an official Marvel article](https://web.archive.org/web/20161015222804/http://marvel.com/news/movies/24062/sony_pictures_entertainment_brings_marvel_studios_into_the_amazing_world_of_spider-man),

> **New Spider-Man Will Appear First in an Upcoming Marvel Film Within Marvel's Cinematic Universe**
>
> ...
>
> Under the deal, **the new Spider-Man** will first appear in a Marvel film
> from Marvel's Cinematic Universe (MCU). Sony Pictures will thereafter
> release the next installment of its $4 billion Spider-Man franchise,
> on July 28, 2017, in a film that will be co-produced by Kevin Feige
> and his expert team at Marvel and Amy Pascal, who oversaw the
> franchise launch for the studio 13 years ago. Together, they will
> collaborate on a new creative direction for the web slinger. Sony
> Pictures will continue to finance, distribute, own and have final
> creative control of the Spider-Man films.

**This constitutes explicit confirmation that the version of Spider-Man appearing in *Civil War* is an entirely new iteration of the character.**

Comment: Just noting that the third film is teasing that he will intersect with the other two Spider-man universes, which will make them canon, albeit in different multiverses.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Marvel does not own the movie rights to Spider-Man but seems as if Sony might be willing to work with Marvel/Disney in the near future since the Oscorp Tower was almost incorporated into the Avengers skyline of New York. Spider-Man could also fit in to the timeline since the Amazing Spider-Man movie came out after the Avengers meaning Peter could have gotten his powers after the events of the Avengers movie.

Comment: "the Oscorp Tower was almost incorporated into the Avengers skyline of New York." Any source for this statement? I've never heard this before. Any evidence for the timeline in either direction?

Comment: @phantom42 See [this piece](http://www.firstshowing.net/2012/amazing-spider-man-almost-tied-into-avengers-and-now-venom/)

Answer (score 3):

## **The *Amazing* Spider-Man is *not* part of the MCU,
 but the *new* Spider-Man is**.

The character Spider-Man, *moving forward*, is *now* part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe due to a deal that was struck between Marvel and Sony.

This does **not** impact the status of *The Amazing Spider-Man* films - they're still *not* part of the MCU. Sony's *The Amazing Spider-Man* films, both 1 and 2, are done and that's that; they are their own universe and aren't part of the MCU or anything. That story is over. None of that changed with the Sony / Marvel deal.

What *did* change is the *future* of the character Spider-Man in film. The ***new*** Spider-Man (with a new actor Tom Holland, [new suit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121894/is-spider-man-cgi-in-the-captain-america-civil-war-trailer), slightly different backstory etc.) *is* part of the MCU, and thus will be appearing in team up MCU films like *Captain America: Civil War* and forthcoming solo MCU Spidey films from Sony, like *[Spider-Man: Homecoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming)*.

The *new*, MCU Spider-Man (with Tom Halland) is a different Spider-Man than the *Amazing* Spider-Man (with Andrew Garfield); they have different, even conflicting storylines, and so on. They're not the same. All future Spider-man films will be MCU Spider-Man films and will therefore ignore the existence of the Andrew Garfield *Amazing* Spider-Man films entirely.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_other_media#Marvel_Cinematic_Universe):

> On February 9, 2015, it was announced that Sony and Disney made a deal for Spider-Man to appear in the Marvel Cinematic Universe with a new film to be released on July 7, 2017. The companies announced on June 23, 2015 that after many auditions, Tom Holland had been cast to play Spider-Man within the MCU.
>
> - The first reference to Spider-Man within the Marvel Cinematic Universe, following the deal with Sony, was in the Ant-Man film. This was confirmed by director, Peyton Reed.
> - Holland makes his first onscreen appearance as Peter Parker / Spider-Man in Captain America: Civil War.
> - Holland will reprise his role in Spider-Man: Homecoming, directed by Jon Watts.

For the reference in *Ant-Man* mentioned above, see  [Who jumps, who swings, who crawls up walls?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110070/who-jumps-who-swings-who-crawls-up-walls)

Comment: This was a good answer at the time! Not anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Currently things changed and there is a reboot happening for Spiderman with him now being part of the MCU even (appearing in Captain America 3: Civil War). Though how much he is part of the MCU aside from this appearance will have to be seen as he was an origianlly unplaned of hero to appear and only got into the MCU because of a recent deal with Sony.