# Is Spider-Man an Avenger?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, spider-man, marvel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is The Amazing Spider-Man part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/is-the-amazing-spider-man-part-of-the-marvel-cinematic-universe)

Is Spider-Man an Avenger? If so, why doesn't he appear in *The Avengers* (2012)?

What defines an Avenger?

Comment: The question could be revised to not be a duplicate if limited to the comic book universe (Earth-616). The tags would also indicate that the core question "Is Spider-Man an Avenger?" would imply the comics and not the movies. Unfortunately the OP included movie references in the body which invited a movie universe answer.

Comment: @dasMetzger The original poster specifically cited a movie by title and release year. That makes their intent clear. Changing it to restrict it just to the MCU would drastically alter that intention. Edits should clear up confusion, not change the asker's question completely. You could ask-and-answer a separate question, restricted to the comic book universe.

Comment: Gotcha. It's unfortunate because the question of Spider-Man being an Avenger is a good one with a good history. Confusion over studio rights is not nearly as fun.

Comment: @dasMetzger Well, like I said... if you think it's interesting information that you have a good grasp on, and you don't see it asked elsewhere on the site, you can ask-and-answer your own question.

Answer (score 8):

Spider-Man can't be in the movie because the film rights to Spider-Man are owned by Sony, and the Avengers is a Disney movie. In the comics, Spider-Man has been an Avenger, but so have dozens of other characters, and there would hardly be room for all of them in a movie. (Various X-Men characters, like Beast, Quicksilver and the Scarlet Witch have a better claim to be Avengers than Spider-Man, but 20th Century Fox owns those rights.)