# When did Spider-Man acquire his powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, spider-man, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

I'm talking about Marvel Cinematic Universe. When Peter Parker talks with Tony Stark in Civil War, he mentions he got his powers 6 months ago. Where does that place it in the timeline?

For example I guess it happened after Avengers, but before Avengers: Age of Ultron? I'm interested in the closest official event (counting the Netflix Daredevil and Jessica Jones as well).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The films in the Marvel Cinematic Universe happen pretty much when they are released, with a few notable exceptions;

- *Captain America: The First Avenger* is set during the Second World War (but the date he was unfrozen in the present matches roughly the time the film was released - mid 2011).
- Despite being released over the course of three years, *The Incredible Hulk*, *Iron Man 2* and *Thor* all happen in the same week, which is known as "Fury's Big Week" and is set at some point in 2010.
- *Iron Man 3* was set at Christmas 2012 but was released in Spring 2013

This means, for example, that the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (released in Spring 2014) happened roughly two years after the events of *Avengers Assemble* (released spring 2012). Being as *Captain America: Civil War* has been released roughly a year after *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we can assume that the two films are set roughly a year apart, meaning *Captain America: Civil War* is set about Spring 2016.

Futhermore, in *Captain America: Civil War* The Vision at one point states;

> "In the eight years since Mr. Stark announced himself as Iron Man...

The original *Iron Man* was released in Spring 2008, further proving that *Captain America: Civil War* takes place roughly now.

Which means that when Peter Parker says he got his powers 6 months ago, he got his powers at some point in late Autumn 2015, post-*Ant-Man* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* but (obviously) pre-*Captain America: Civil War*.

The nearest event in the timeline to the period where Peter Parker gained his powers would be the *Agents of SHIELD* season three episodes "Many Heads, One Tale" and "Closure", or some point during the middle of the season season of *Daredevil* (which seems to span from late-summer 2015 to mid-Winter 2015).

It's also worth noting that at the end of *Ant-Man*, Sam Wilson is looking for Scott Lang after their brief fight at the Avengers Facility, and a woman he's talking to tells him that they've got "A guy that jumps. A guy that swings. A guy that crawls up walls". As pointed out by @ibid in the comments on this answer, if we assume there is a time jump between the end of the main story of *Ant-Man* and this scene, the person the woman is referring to could be Spider-Man.

Comment: Great answer! Do you think you could provide few of these exceptions for the sake of argument?

Comment: So does this mean the thing at the end of Ant-Man was not referring to Spidey?

Comment: @ibid According to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110071/24087), maybe it is, maybe it isn't - but judging from the timeline of when Peter claims he got his powers, in-universe it isn't a reference, even if it is a reference out-of-universe.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Is it possible that there were a time jump at the end of Ant-Man?

Comment: @ibid That's a damn good point; yes, there is. It could be that the final scene of *Ant-Man* takes place some time after the main story, which would help make the timelines sync up better. I'll add that to the answer.