# Spider-Man not in Avengers

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, marvel, the-avengers-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is the Hulk in the Avengers the same as in the other movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16062/is-the-hulk-in-the-avengers-the-same-as-in-the-other-movies)

Why wasn't Spider-Man featured in the movie 'Avengers',even though he's an ace superhero of the Marvel Universe? Any history or conflicts behind this.

Comment: Note that the question I linked is about the Hulk, but the accepted answer answers your question, which would make this a duplicate.

Comment: Likely because the Toby Maguire Spiderman trilogy is over and the reboot doesn't release until July.

Comment: But sincerely does that anything to do with him featuring in a team ?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - there are 2 reasons, one in universe and 1 out of universe. The linked answer only covers out of universe reason

Comment: The in-universe reason is that the Marvel Cinematic Universe literally doesn't have Spider-man in it.  At least until the rights revert to Marvel.

Comment: Sooner it will, as per the [news](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/what-would-have-to-happen-to-merge-the-spider-man-franchise-and-the-avengers-fra/30945#30945)

Answer (score 7):

From [Marvel Wikia](http://marvelcomics.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_wasn%27t_spiderman_in_the_Avengers_movie):

> Marvel does not have the movie rights to Spider-Man. For now, only Sony Pictures can legally put Spider-Man in a movie.

---

Also, in-universe, Spiderman wasn't part of the Avengers team, but of a later [New Avengers](http://www.comicvine.com/new-avengers/65-42520/).

Answer (score 3):

Marvel Studios, The studio that did The Avengers movie (and the related movies) does not currently hold the rights to Spiderman. The rights are still currently owned by Sony Pictures, who are releasing a new Spiderman movie this summer.