# Whose fist dent is there on the seclusion retreat cabin of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the S02E14 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Coulson took Skye to a secret seclusion retreat facility of S.H.I.E.L.D. which was built by Bruce Banner.

In the next episode, a fist dent on Vibranium-lined Honeycomb wall was shown:

[image: fist dent]

Whose fist dent is this?

I debated about this in comments of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86289/why-doesnt-s-h-i-e-l-d-put-hulk-on-the-index-and-lock-him-away). I believe that the fist dent was made by Captain America (others believe that it was Hulk's) because Coulson told Skye that Rogers spent a few weeks there after he was defrosted. It doesn't prove the dent was made by him, but *punching in anger* is his style (it again proves nothing). The facility was designed to withstand Hulk-size force, but it can be generic specification to deal with strange guys. It doesn't prove that Banner stayed there. And, even if he stayed there, it's possible he didn't go haywire to create dents all over the place. Also, it's not Hulk's style to punch on wall. He just cries, throw objects, and run here and there when he is angry.
In short, we can't conclude the answer logically with verbal data. Or, if you can, please answer.

Can you compute and prove using graphics that that fist dent was made by Captain America or Hulk or some other guy?

Comment: It's clearly a Hulk-sized fist print. We know Hulk's alter ego built the cabin. Why is this even a question? If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck... (And like phantom42 said, if you think punching a wall is somehow out of character for the Hulk, you clearly need to watch/read more about the Hulk.)

Comment: Episode details and dialogue indicate the Hulk tapped the wall. And it isn't vibranium neither.

Comment: @Ihor Give me the dialogue which indicates that. That can be answer.

Comment: "The one that Banner built?" And who else has a big right hand/fist? It's as big as Skye's head even though it's further away in the view.

Comment: @Ihor That dialogue proves nothing.. I have included this in the question.

Comment: Are Captain America’s hands that size. No.

Comment: @Ihor How about Captain America with Punching Gloves?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite See previous comment..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: hold on. [You might be onto something here](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/images/Captain-Amerihulk.png).

Comment: Now THAT's snarky.

Comment: Crap. What if it's that kid from down the block?! http://www.smh.com.au/ffxImage/urlpicture_id_1047749925285_2003/03/21/21hullkhands.jpg

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: hold on. You might be onto something here.–  Paul D. Waite  _  What are 'Punching Gloves'? Is that like walking shoes? This discussion should refocus to answering  - Why isn't it the Hulk? Are really big hands an allergic reaction spreading amongst the players in the MCU? Oh no, Capt. Kirk had them in Star Trek after the injections given by McCoy! And his tongue swole too. Maybe there are big lick tracks somewhere in the cabin. Maybe the maid punched the wall because the tip envelope was light. Discuss.

Comment: @Omegacron: snark worthy of upvotes!

Comment: Could still be iron man in the hulkbuster armor

Comment: @Andreas: could be Tony Stark with a lump hammer and some artistic urges. “I call it... Hulk-Looking Fist-Print.”

Comment: I want to see an example of these gloves you keep referring to that could even conceivably maybe sorta kinda make an impression on something that looks and acts like steel, but is significantly more durable.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think it was Thor with a fist-peen hammer.

Comment: @IhorSypko: “Is that like walking shoes?” More like kicking shoes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no way a normal sized human left the dent there with their fist.

Consider the size difference of Skye's fist versus the dent in the wall.

[image: Skye holding her hand up to the fist dent in the wall]

Skye has her fist on a slightly odd angle/bend, but even if we assume that her fist is as big as her entire fist and wrist, her entire fist still fits in just a few of the finger joints in the dent.

[image: Same image as the previous one now with red outlines!]

A normal-sized human (e.g. Captain America) with immense super power could conceivably punch hard enough to dent the Vibranium, but the force behind the punch would only affect how deep the impression was, not the length/width of it.

So, given that a normal sized human could not do this damage (even if he's wearing "punching gloves", *who* left it?

I asked Maurissa Tancharoen, one of the head writers and producers of the show.

> [image: question]
>
> @MoTancharoen Any chance of settling this for us?  Is the fist print Hulk's? Who else could possibly do it?

While not 100% explicitly saying, "Yes, it was the Hulk", [she does say that my conclusion is "astute".](https://twitter.com/MoTancharoen/status/588741365116219392)

> [image: answer]
>
> @phntm42 Seems like an astute conclusion...

So, to sum up:

- The fist print is too large for a normal human
- The house is described as being built for/by (at least in part) Bruce Banner
- Coulson mentions the place being built to withstand Banner
- The head writer/producer says that the Banner theory is a good/accurate assessment.

**The fist print is from The Hulk.**

Comment: You are assuming that Captain America punched bare-handed..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: as opposed to punching with gloves. Metal gloves, presumably. That are shaped like big fists.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Vibranium gloves maybe..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: yup, big fist-shaped vibranium gloves. Obviously.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Heck, it could even have been [Sheldon Cooper](http://www.geekology.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Sheldon-con-manos-de-Hulk.jpg)

Answer (score 24):

In the next episode when *Alternative* SHIELD finds out where Skye is they say:

> The one that Banner built?

This cabin was constructed by Bruce Banner, and it is assumed that as the Hulk he is the one who punched the dent in the wall. This makes sense particularly when you consider how large the dent is. It is much larger than a normal sized fist, which is what Captain America has.

Here we see Captain America's original steel shield after being punched by Red Skull (who basically has the same strength as him). You see it is a normal sized fist print.

[image: Red Skull's fist dent in Captain America's original shield]

After Banner abandoned it, the cabin apparently became a safe house for people with powers who may not have total control over themselves yet or were initially feared by SHIELD.

**The only other person I could conceive of making an impression this large would be Abomination, but I highly doubt SHIELD would allow him to stay at a cabin somewhere.**

Comment: Another point: Rogers is strong, but are we really saying he's strong enough to put an impressive dent in a wall *specifically designed to contain the Hulk*?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that the cabin was built by Banner and it proves nothing. Banner could just have assisted S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I feel like there is absolutely no reason to believe it was Steve Rogers.

Comment: Roger's super-strength would affect how *deep* the impression would go, but not the lenght/width to the extent that it is shown.

Comment: @JackBNimble 1. He stayed there. 2. *Punching in Anger* is his style (Hulk just cries and run here and there when he is angry).

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I have added a picture of when Red Skull punched his shield, the dent is normal sized. There is no reason to think Rogers is significantly strong than Red Skull was.

Comment: "Hulk just cries and run here and there when he is angry" I'm not sure you've ever watched anything with The Hulk.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: “1. He stayed there. 2. Punching in Anger is his style.” And 3, HIS HAND IS NOT THAT BIG.

Comment: @phantom42 How about Captain America with Punching Gloves?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite See previous comment..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 ah yeah, definitely what the writers intended.

Answer (score 3):

Look, not only is the dent big enough that I'm reasonably certain that Hulk left it, when I examine it more closely, something else becomes pretty pro Hulk.

The diameter of the fingers in the dent are at least 1 1/2 inches wide. Hulk or others like him are the only beings with digits that massive coupled with that much raw power.

Comment: You're assuming that Captain America punched bare-handed. There are things called Gloves in the world..

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it was Hulk's.  It can be seen by the size of the fist and it is mentioned in the conversation that was between agent Weaver and another agent in the same episode where one agent informs agent Weaver that Skye's location is "The Retreat". Her reply gives us the answer as she says;

> Why would Coulson take Skye to a place built by Banner?

That is Bruce Banner: The Incredible Hulk.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that The Retreat is the same cabin we see at the end of *The Incredible Hulk*, except with a few modifications. When I first saw the dent that Skye uncovered in the wall, it immediately reminded me of that cabin. Bruce Banner could have possibly made contact with SHIELD and Fury had the place built. Whether it was to contain him if he got out of control, or if it were a place for Banner to learn to control his anger, I don't know. I suppose it is also possible that Banner built it then Fury added some modifications to it so it would be more like a safe house, like it is now.

Comment: ...but whose fist dent is it?

Answer (score -1):

In the *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* episode *2x15 - One Door Closes* at time index 27:50, Barbara "Bobbie" Morse was discussing Skye's whereabouts with the governing counncil of the *Real Shield*.

Agent Weaver said about *The Retreat*, that Coulson was

> ... taking her to the house that **Banner** built ...

indicating that Dr. Bruce "The Hulk" Banner built the hut, and it can be guessed he caused the indentation in question.

Comment: This does not really seem to provide much of an answer to the question. What information can be found by watching the video that you mention?

Comment: i am simply trying to make a guess , what if it was built by Dr bruce banner

Comment: Sure, but as this stands it’s not really an answer. Someone reading this just couldn’t know the answer to the question. Could you add some explanation of what that episode says?

Comment: yaa, it was when the barbra the shield agent was discussing with fallen shield members about, where did the coulson hid skye. and agent weaver spoke that :-" bold,taking her to the house that banner built

Comment: OK, could you edit that into the post, then? Ideally, someone reading this post should be able to learn the answer to the question.

Comment: yaa, it was when the barbra the shield agent was discussing with fallen shield members about, where did the coulson hid skye. and agent weaver spoke that :-" bold,taking her to the house that banner built

Comment: Yes. Could you use the [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/141773/edit) button here to add that to your answer?

Comment: is it good now.....................

Comment: It could still use some editing. For example, what does the word “bold” mean? Are you trying to put something in bold?

Comment: this would be better i guess, its done

Answer (score -3):

I think it's the cabin that we saw at the end of *The Incredible Hulk*, when it was still Edward Norton playing him. Therefore, it is probably the Hulk's fist.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of explicitly stating what your answer appeared to be here. If that wasn't the case please [edit] your post to clarify exactly whose fist you believe this to have been.